# How to insert a double inverted comma " in a bash string in UNIX bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a bash string like

```
--db newdb --collection newcoll --type=csv --fields name,value"
```

I want to insert a double inverted comma `"` in this string after fields,  output should be like

```
--db newdb --collection newcoll --type=csv --fields "name,value"
```

Comment: escape them....

Comment: Generally speaking, argument lists should never be stored in strings. See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) describing the problems this practice causes, and alternate solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must *escape* them. There is written a lot on this topic on the internet, just google it and you will see what escaping is. To show you how it is done I will give you an example:

```
x="--db newdb --collection newcoll --type=csv --fields \"name,value"
```

Compare it to what you have and you will find a difference real quick. But still, go google what escaping is... A useful link would be [Quotes and escaping](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting) but find some others on your own.

Comment: Probably better to provide well-vetted references rather than encouraging folks to Google -- there's a lot of garbage written about bash with high PageRank scores (the ABS, being bash's equivalent to W3Schools in the HTML/JavaScript arena, comes to mind). And the OP's question *implies* that they're trying to generate a string to evaluate later -- if that's the case, while you're answering the question correctly (but for missing the last literal quote), the question itself is buggy.

Comment: I find that link OK. Certainly not the best, but OK to start with. Indeed, since the string looks like flags with arguments provided to some script.

Comment: Yes, the link you provided is indeed a good one; the bash-hackers' wiki is a solid reference. It's the encouragement to "just google it" I'm taking issue with.

Comment: I agree with you. It is hard to distinguish garbage from treasure when you are beginning with something but better get used to it at the start then to get used to always getting what you want immediately... Cause there will come a day one has to help oneself cause there aren't other options...

Comment: Extending the metaphor -- our purpose here on StackOverflow is to be a source of treasure. Sure, people need to learn to help themselves, but giving them the best possible start to that (in terms of the grounding/basis on which to filter the wheat from the chaff) is what we're here for.

Answer (score 2):

The symbols you want are called "double quotes".

#### TL;DR: Use An Array Instead

Don't try to store literal quotes in a string *at all*, if the purpose of that string is to generate part of an argument list. Instead, store the data you want in an array, and expand that array when running your program:

```
# THIS IS THE CORRECT/BEST PRACTICE
args=( --db newdb --collection newcoll --type=csv --fields "name,value" )
myprog "${args[@]}"
```

The above properly treats the quotes as *syntactic* rather than literal: It puts `name,value` into the argument following `--fields`, just as `myprog --fields "name,value"` would have done.

---

#### In Context: Don't Store Argument Lists In Strings

Instead of this:

```
### THIS IS BUGGY: SEE http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050
args='--db newdb --collection newcoll --type=csv --fields "name,value"'
myprog $args
```

...or this:

```
### THIS IS BUGGY: SEE http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050
args="--db newdb --collection newcoll --type=csv --fields \"name,value\""
myprog $args
```

...or this:

```
### THIS HAS SECURITY VULNERABILITIES IF UNTRUSTED DATA IS SUBSTITUTED
### SEE http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048
args='--db newdb --collection newcoll --type=csv --fields "name,value"'
eval "myprog $args"
```

---

#### Literal Answer Out-Of-Context: Escaping Mechanisms for Double Quotes

All of the following will pass `echo` a single literal double quote:

```
echo \"
echo '"'
echo "\""
```

...and can be used within substrings...

```
str=hello\"world
str='hello"world'
str="hello\"world"
```

...or even mixed with other quoting types:

```
str="$var"'"'world   ## $var is in double quotes, " is in single quotes, world is unquoted
```

But again -- none of the above is appropriate in the use case at hand.